# How to automatically send certain emaIls when opening outlook?

Tags: outlook

Any advise anyone on how to automatically send email when opening outlook?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.outlookforums.com/showthread.php?17124-How-do-I-automatically-send-recieve-upon-opening-outlook-2007) might help, altough the interface is terrible.

I'll keep looking for more!